# Find derivative of inverse of function $y=2x^3-6x$ and calculate it's value at $x=-2$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

> > Find derivative of inverse of function $y=2x^3-6x$ and calculate it's value at $x=-2$.

**My Approach:**

We know that $(f^{-1}(f(x)))=x$

Taking derivative both side

$(f^{-1}(f(x)))' \cdot f'(x)=1$

$(f^{-1}(f(x)))'=\frac{1}{f'(x)}=\dfrac{1}{6x^2-6}$

We want to find $f^{-1}(-2)$ so we must have $f(x)=-2$ i.e. $\quad$$2x^3-6x=-2$

$\implies$ $2x^3-6x+2=0$

I can't find any integer root from here.

But given answer is $\frac{1}{18}$

**I know other method to solve this problem but can we solve using my approach used above?**

Comment: The starting point of your approach is fine. However notice that you are trying to evaluate the derivative of the inverse at $y=-2$ as opposed to the demanded $x=-2$.

Comment: If the answer is correct, then your understanding of problem statement is wrong. Given answer corresponds to problem statement, where $x=-2$ is not argument but value of inverse function in point, where you need to find derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the inverse of $f$ as
$g(y)=f^{-1}(y)$

As you wrote, it holds $g[f(x)] = x$.
Taking derivative both sides and applying chain rule yields

$$
g'[f(x)] f'(x) 
= 1$$

Thus
$$
g'[f(x)]
= \frac{1}{6(x^2-1)}
$$
Evaluated at $x=-2$, the RHS is 1/18 as requested.